# Interactive Workflow Tool

Tags: workflow

I’m interested in making an interactive work-flow tool like the one on this [New York Times (NYT) website.](https://archive.nytimes.com/www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/06/14/us/how-the-supreme-court-could-rule-on-the-health-care-law.html?hp)

[image: New York Times Workflow Example]

The members of my team would click on Yes or No buttons on the work-flow tool, and it would show interactive messages similar to pressing the buttons on the NYT website. I have heard of online tools like Survey Monkey but they can't accomplish this kind of interactivity. I am not a web designer and I don’t know the coding to do this, so I want to use an online platform/tool to do this.  Can anyone recommend an online platform or tool that is simple to use and can create such a workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try one of them for creating forms:

- https://www.formsite.com/
- https://www.cognitoforms.com/
- https://www.typeform.com/

But I'm not sure that it can be interactive like on your website. On your website it doing in code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a survey tool would provide the functionality you need. Although most of them provide similar behaviors (step process with interdependencies between questions), [Typeform](https://www.typeform.com/surveys/) uses a much more welcoming user interface.